# I want to know how would I show products price unit on delivery slip report

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14, odoo-15

**I want to know how would I show products price on delivery slip report on odoo 15.**

Comment: You should print purchase/sale order for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The delivery slip gets values from  `_get_aggregated_product_quantities` function

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/models/stock_move_line.py#L777

So basically you can inherit the following view to add price field through `product_id`
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/report/report_deliveryslip.xml